# no route found from source to destination in ios map

Tags: ios, maps

when open IOS map on my application i found my location marker and my destination marker but no route or any option and this message comes to me "no route found from source to destination" , help please

Comment: That error is usually thrown, when there is no actual route between the two points (or at least MapKit can't find one). Check with other destinations/sources.

Answer (score 0):

if your destination is in middle of sea or in mountains. so there will be no route from source to destination. and if there is no route then map will throw this error. 
Also there may be a route for walk but not for car or there may be a route for car but on that route there will be no public transport. so check which option you have selected.
good luck. if you have any further question drop it in comment here.

Comment: my destination inside city no sea or mountains, i dont know where is car route option or walk route